# How to aggregate to have the _id as a object property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collection:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {
    name: "Name 1",
    <other properties here>
  }
},
{
  _id: 2,
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {
    name: "Name 2",
    <other properties here>
  }
}
```

How can I write a MongoDB Aggregate query to return the following ?

```
{
  data: {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Name 1",
      <other properties here>
    }
  }
},
{
  data: {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Name 2",
      <other properties here>
    }
  }
}
```

So, the `_id` should become an attribute of `properties` and each document should be returned as  an object of `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple structure manipulation will suffice:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       $project: {
           data: {
             type: "$type",
             properties: { 
                $mergeObjects: [
                 {_id: "$_id"},
                 "$properties"
                ]
             }
           }
       }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

1- If you need only the _id to be inside the properties, and not in data object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      type: {
        $first: "$type"
      },
      properties: {
        $first: {
          _id: "$_id",
          name: "$properties.name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "data._id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mCE6Rz-EMD3)

2- If it's matter only to get the _id inside the the properties object, and you don't care if it's in data or not

you can use this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      type: {
        $first: "$type"
      },
      properties: {
        $first: {
          _id: "$_id",
          name: "$properties.name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
])
```

check this [Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8WYwRix4k_R)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to utilize your dataset as it was not RFC 8259 formatted. 
 However assuming your dataset is properly formatted like below.  The issued command would be near close provided the fields matched

```
    {
   "data":{
      "Feature":{
         "properties":{
            "_id1":[
               "object_of_data1",
               "object_of_data2",
               "object_of_data3"
            ],
            "_id2":[
               "object_of_data1",
               "object_of_data2",
               "object_of_data3"
            ],
            "_id3":[
               "object_of_data1",
               "object_of_data2",
               "object_of_data3"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would then use the command:

```
 db.orders.aggregate([
       { $match: { properties: "_id1" } },
       { $group: { _id1: "object_of_data1", "object_of_data2" 
    "object_of_data3" } } }
    ])
```

For further reading please see: [Aggregation Commands Comparison](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-commands-comparison/)